# Cross-Browser optimization for HTML/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, zooming

I started with HTML/CSS about 3 weeks ago, so I'm still very much a rookie. I've really thrown myself into it, and the work really pays off imo :) After mastering the basics, I wanted a challenge on a whole new level, and offered a friend to code him a website. He was all over the idea, and I started coding like a maniac. Now I'm pretty far in, and realized that I haven't done any cross-browser testing. The whole website looks off in chrome, with 100% zoom in Firefox being ~125% zoom in Chrome.

I recorded my screen to clarify what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DKB9L3R40o

JS I grabed from the Web:

Animations : animate.css and WOW.js

Slideshow: Awkward Showcase

Problematic is, that because of the Animations, I can't just use:

*{background-image: URL("img/...");

...;

...;

...;
}

Instead I have to add an img in HTML and then resize and position it in CSS.
As I said before, I am still a beginner, and of course my code doesn't look as refined as that from a senior programmer.

Anyway, here is my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alte Brücke Mostar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montez|Allura|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Arvo:400,400italic|Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    new WOW().init();
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.aw-showcase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#showcase").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width:          1920,
        content_height:         916,
        fit_to_parent:          false,
        auto:                   true,
        interval:               3000,
        continuous:             true,
        loading:                true,
        tooltip_width:          200,
        tooltip_icon_width:     32,
        tooltip_icon_height:    32,
        tooltip_offsetx:        18,
        tooltip_offsety:        0,
        arrows:                 false,
        buttons:                false,
        btn_numbers:            true,
        keybord_keys:           true,
        mousetrace:             false, /* Trace x and y coordinates for the mouse */
        pauseonover:            false,
        stoponclick:            false,
        transition:             'hslide', /* hslide/vslide/fade */
        transition_delay:       0,
        transition_speed:       1500,
        show_caption:           'onload', /* onload/onhover/show */
        thumbnails:             false,
        thumbnails_position:    'outside-last', /* outside-last/outside-first/inside-last/inside-first */
        thumbnails_direction:   'vertical', /* vertical/horizontal */
        thumbnails_slidex:      1, /* 0 = auto / 1 = slide one thumbnail / 2 = slide two thumbnails / etc. */
        dynamic_height:         false, /* For dynamic height to work in webkit you need to set the width and height of images in the source. Usually works to only set the dimension of the first slide in the showcase. */
        speed_change:           true, /* Set to true to prevent users from swithing more then one slide at once. */
        viewline:               false, /* If set to true content_width, thumbnails, transition and dynamic_height will be disabled. As for dynamic height you need to set the width and height of images in the source. */
        custom_function:        null /* Define a custom function that runs on content change */
    });
});

</script>
<body>
<div id="container" class="wow fadeInLeft" >

<header id="head">
    <h1 class="wow fadeInRight">Mostar Alte Brücke</h1>
    <nav id="navigation">
        <p><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="bosnisch.html">Bosnische Küche</a> | <a href="speisekarte.html">Speisekarte</a> | <a href="about.html">Über uns</a> | <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a> | <a href="location.html">Anfahrt</a></p>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="food">
    <div id="showcase" class="showcase">
    <div class="showcase-slide">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
            <img src="img/food3.jpg" alt="Kaviar">
            </div>
        </div><!--Ende showcase-content-->
    </div><!--Ende showcase-slide-->

    <div class="showcase-slide">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
            <img src="img/food4.jpg" alt="Huhn">
            </div>
        </div><!--Ende showcase-content-->
    </div><!--Ende showcase-slide-->

    <div class="showcase-slide">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
            <img src="img/food5.jpg" alt="Stew">
            </div>
        </div><!--Ende showcase-content-->
    </div><!--Ende showcase-slide-->

    <div class="showcase-slide">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
            <img src="img/food6.jpg" alt="Faschiertes">
            </div>
        </div><!--Ende showcase-content-->
    </div><!--Ende showcase-slide-->

    </div><!--Ende showcase-->



    </div><!--Ende showcase-->

</div><!--Ende Container-->


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS going with it:

```
*{
font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility ;
}
#head{
margin-top: 10%;
padding: 10px 32% 0 32%;
    position: fixed;
    /*background-color: #e4e4e4;*/
    z-index: 2;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Montez';
    font-size:75px;
    margin: 0 0 -10px 0px;
    color:#c0392b;
    font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
#navigation{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}
#navigation a{
    color: #c0392b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#food{
    max-width:110%;
    max-height:120%;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -40px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Long story short: What can I do to change my code so it fills the whole screen on all browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@**iMrFelix** to start off with for a "rookie" that is a great code structure, 
When I was starting out, cross browser testing was hell for me,
I made a whole website tested in Firefox and later realised it was out of proportion in chrome & internet explorer so to tackle this I downloaded browser-stack, browser stack helps you with cross browser testing without having to download another browser.

As for CSS backgrounds you need to tell your css file where the image is from **that** css file **NOT** from the location of the current HTML document.
So if thecurrent HTML document is in the root folder and your css is in the **/css** folder you need to write:

```
 background-image:url('../img/location/to/your-bg.png');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I know about the css background property, but it doesn't work for my site, because if I apply the background to all of the page (* in css), all the animations get the weird background aswell, so when the text flies in, there is a bit of background hanging off the sides of the text. Otherwise it would be easy :)

Comment: Try no-repeat on background or background size cover.